# how handle error in Logic app error handle

Tags: azure, logging, handler

I like to configure logic app is there is any failure inside it and then it has to sent email alert there failure into logic app.

Please help in that. If you did the same please sent it with sample screen.

Comment: This documentation outlines an example of how to do this under the "Manage the run after' behavior" section https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-exception-handling

Answer (score 0):

I have created a sample flow with parallel flows where both receives error. I have created a variable and appended the errors of each of the flow to the string variable. Finally, I have sent the resultant string to email. Below is the flow of my logic app.

*RESULTS :*

[image]

*IN MY EMAIL :*

[image]